# How to create a script, which runs another script in separate terminal window and does not wait?

Tags: shell, executable, gnome-terminal

I wrote the following

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/bin/red5-1.0.0
gnome-terminal --working-directory=. -x red5.sh
```

`red5.sh` is the script to run (this is java written media server).

My script above opens new terminal but with error message

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "red5.sh" (No such file or directory)
```

What can be the cause? I am at Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory does not affect your `$PATH`<sup>1</sup>, thus I guess what's happening can be understood if you do the same thing in a terminal, i.e.

```
$ cd ~/bin/red5-1.0.0
$ red5.sh
```

will not work either; what does work is one of the following:

```
$ cd ~/bin/red5-1.0.0
$ ./red5.sh            # note the relative path to the script
```

or

```
$ cd ~/bin/red5-1.0.0
$ export PATH=~/bin/red5-1.0.0:$PATH   # add the path to $PATH which is where 
$ red5.sh                              # the shell looks for red5.sh
```

So, guessing that `gnome-terminal` works similar (regarding where it looks for executables), you could probably alter your script in one of these ways, too.

1: If your `$PATH` does not contain `.`, as Kevin pointed out (How about other relative paths, btw?).

Comment: Great! This was a mistake!

Comment: But this solution will run the script waiting until it ends. He wants it not to wait, so the `&` symbol should be appended at the end of the running command.

Comment: Just a note, "The working directory does not affect your `$PATH`".  This isn't *always* true.  Some people have the current directory (`export PATH=.:/usr/local/bin:...`) in which case the effective PATH will differ based on the directory you are in.